# Concurrent streaming from filesrc to udpsink and appsink using python opencv with gstreamer support

Tags: python-3.6, gstreamer, opencv, python

Hi I am trying to open a video file using opencv with gstreamer support in python. The idea is to grab frames from the file and to simultaneously pass it to my python3 application for processing while also encoding it into h264 and sending it to a udpsink. Each of these streams work when being run independently but I run into errors when trying to run it together. This pipeline works if I pull from a web camera instead of a filesrc.

The code that I used to open the cv2.VideoCapture is below. I am running this on a TX2 with Jetpack 4.3 and a recompiled Opencv 4.1.1

```
video_stream = cv2.VideoCapture("filesrc location=video.mp4 ! \
    qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! tee name=t \
    t. ! queue leaky=downstream ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink \
    t. ! queue leaky=downstream ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)320, height=(int)240 ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264, streamformat=byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=1234")
```

The error I get is as follows

```
[ WARN:0] global /usr/local/src/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1757) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module demux reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global /usr/local/src/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (886) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /usr/local/src/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

Any suggestions on how I should proceed? Thanks!

Comment: I have a few tips for debugging the problem:

 - `qtdemux` is giving an error. Are you sure your video file is quicktime? 

 - If you don't know about the file mux/encoding structure you can use `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin ! fakesink -v` to see the details. (If you can share the output of this step here we can help you better)

 - For more verbosity on gstreamer you can set verbosity level by `export GST_DEBUG=3` (or another log level, but 3 will be sufficient for your case)

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I went to check but unfortunately it is a quicktime video. It may be helpful to know that running this pipeline without the stream to udpsink work. I have attached the first few lines of the debug `/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/quicktime, variant=(string)iso`

Comment: It definitely helps to know that. Could you try the replacing the part after queue with `fakesink` in the last line? Let's see if it works with fakesink.

Comment: Hi, fakesink after queue will cause the pipeline to run. The pipeline fails when the fakesink is after the nvvidconv... After some more research I believe this to be a different data flow rate issue... Ie my cv2.VideoCapture is pulling at a slow rate than the h264 encoder. I wonder if there is any way to solve this? Putting videorate elements to slow down the appsink chain doesnt seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to add another nvvidconv before the tee. Not sure exactly why, but it allows the entire pipeline to flow correctly.

```
video_stream = cv2.VideoCapture("filesrc location=video.mp4 ! \
    qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! tee name=t \
    t. ! queue leaky=downstream ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink \
    t. ! queue leaky=downstream ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)320, height=(int)240 ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264, streamformat=byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=1234")
```